# Prove the mapping $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x+e^y,y+e^z,z+e^x)$ is locally invertible.

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

> Show that the mapping $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$, $(x,y,z)\mapsto (u,v,w)$ which is defined by $$\begin{align*}
> u&=x+e^y\\
> v&= y+e^z\\
>  w &=z+e^x
> \end{align*}$$is locally invertible  everywhere.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mapping is clearly smooth. By the [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), all we have to check is that the [Jacobian determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is nonzero everywhere:

> $$\left|\matrix{1 & e^y & 0\\0&1&e^z\\e^x&0&1}\right|=1+e^xe^ye^z>0.$$